# FTP server | Filezilla | windows server

Tags: windows, ftp

I have a windows 2012 server running Filezilla server for FTP. I have setup the server with a user which has a directory set to home dir.

See picture to see setup:

However, when I connect to the FTP - it connects fine, but displays this error and does not allow me to see the directory:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (145,3,82,63,196,41)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Why you don't use the windows integrated FTP Server? Via IIS-Manager Role? With this you can easy set up rulesets and filerights.

Comment: I dont like it, having to setup a windows user for each ftp user. Opens up too many cans of worms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the log you show you have a firewall blocking your connection or you did not fully forward/open all ports.

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (185,7,81,67,196,41)
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
```

You can see here that the client is entering passive mode on port [50218](http://www.serv-u.com/respcode.asp?resp=227). You most likely did not forward this port and most likely not the entire configured passive range.

According to the FileZilla [wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Passive_mode_2) you can see the port range under FileZilla Server Options and then Passive mode settings. Be sure to open/forward the ports listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Filezilla server with a predefined passive ports range, add those ports to the firewall in your router and assign virtual server allowing communication.

add port 990 and 21 or the port you decided to use.